# Linq Group List by date with object List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Im looking for a way to get a grouped List by date.

I successfully sorted my list by date, but i can figure how get an List with all grouped object in the new list.

```
List<PersonneWithDate> personneList = GetPersonnelsByDay ();
var groups = from p in personneList
    group p by new { day = p.Date.Day, month = p.Date.Month , year= p.Date.Year } into d
    select new { dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", d.Key.day,d.Key.month,d.Key.year), count = d.Count()};
```

Give me an list with an object that have dt and count but i want all the PersonneWithDate that are grouped too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `ToList` method to get the each group of `PersonneWithDate` as a list:

```
    //...
    select new { dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",d.Key.day,d.Key.month,d.Key.year),
                 count = d.Count(),
                 persons=d.ToList()
               };
```

Comment: Short and right, thanks for your answer. Work for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that

1. Instead group by anonymous object containing day, month and year, you can group by `Date.Date`
2. Then select creating a anonymous object with 3 properties

   1. **dt** of type `string`, with the date in string format
   2. **count** of type `int`, with total of people in this date
   3. **persons** of type `IEnumerable<PersonneWithDate>` that contains the collection of persons.

See the code below:

```cs
List<PersonneWithDate> personneList = GetPersonnelsByDay();
var groups = from p in personneList
             group p by p.Date.Date into d
             select new
             {
                 dt = d.Key.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                 count = d.Count(),
                 // if you need that persons collection should be a list, then call .ToList() after Select()
                 persons = d.Select(t => t)
             };
```

Lambda way

```
List<PersonneWithDate> personneList = GetPersonnelsByDay();
var groups = personneList.GroupBy(p => p.Date.Date).Select(d => new
{
    dt = d.Key.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    count = d.Count(),
    // if you need that persons collection should be a list, then call .ToList() after Select()
    persons = d.Select(t => t)
});
```

The `Date` property from a `DateTime` truncate the time, so if you have this `new DateTime(2015,1,1,12,30,59)` when you access the Date property, the Date is equals to `new DateTime(2015,1,1)`, so

```
new DateTime(2015,1,1,12,30,59).Date == new DateTime(2015,1,1)
```

Is true

Comment: Awesome, i read something very late yersteday about the truncate of DateTime but i didn't realize that it can be use like you do. Now that i know this i can use your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but is this what you're after?

```
List<PersonneWithDate> personneList = GetPersonnelsByDay();
var groups =
(
    from p in personneList
    group p by p.Date.Date into d
    select new
    {
        dt = d.Key.ToShortDateString(),
        count = d.Count(),
        personnel = d.ToList(),
    }
).ToList();
```

(I simplified the query grouping a little too.)